# Estimated fees too high

Tags: polkadot-js

Estimated fees for some extrinsics look significantly higher (4-10x) that the final used ones.
This example of a `delegate` call highlight this: https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/16420739-2 (see `estimated` fee vs `used`)

Is there a way to improve the estimation? Or is this something specific to this extrinsic that could be improved somehow?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the extrinsic [`delegate`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ced1659017c823e8a73183e051976bfd756f8605/frame/conviction-voting/src/lib.rs#L240C7-L243) you can see the pre_dispatch weight is determined based on the [`MaxVotes`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ced1659017c823e8a73183e051976bfd756f8605/frame/conviction-voting/src/lib.rs#L121-L122) configurable. Unfortunately the **actual** amount of votes are only known after execution. If therefore there is only one vote, the difference between the `estimated` fee and `used` fee can be quite significant.

Comment: Good catch! Somehow I overlooked this. 
So the weight depends on the max number of concurrent votes allowed per address, 512 as of now for both kusama and polkadot.

Thanks!

Comment: Crucially, the pre-dispatch fees are computed entirely statically, as in the transaction is not executed in order to estimate the fee, therefore any refund is not seen. _If_ a DApp really wants to give you an accurate estimate, they should `DryRun` the extrinsic and measure how much fee was charged. But this is inefficient, and not very privacy/MEV friendly.